# How to get arguments

Tags: javascript

The objective of this code is to write the `rev` function and make it return the following  Obviously its

Comment: Where is the `rev` function?

Comment: You've posted the expected outcome of what you want, can you post the function you've got now and the input please

Comment: im sorry guys, I thought I posted the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's what you wanted. Since you are passing a function as a parameter you are using high order function or a decorator , hope this helps
check this [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-decorators-what-they-are/)

```
function welcome(name) {
   return `Welcome ${name}`;
}

function bye(name) {
  return `Bye ${name}`;
}


function rev(wrapped) {
   return function() {
     const result = wrapped.apply(this,arguments);
     return `${result}, ${result.split(" ").reverse().join(" ")}`
    }
 }

 const revWelcome = rev(welcome);
 const revBye = rev(bye);

 console.log(revWelcome('James'))
 console.log(revBye('Bond'))
```

Comment: Hello,
No that is not what I wanted. I have edited the post to add the code. Hope you understand what I want now

Comment: if you want them be reversed why don't you do it in the callback itself??

Comment: i have edited my answer take a look test it see if that what you wanted

Comment: THANK YOU SO SOOOOOO MUCH <3

Comment: glad it helped you